# Format currency number

Tags: delphi, currency, delphi-xe

```
procedure TfrmTESTE.edtVALOR(Sender: TObject);
  begin
    inherited;
    if (Trim(edtArea.text) <> '') and (Trim(edtVALOR.text) <> '') then
        edtVALOR.text := floattostr(StrToFloat(edtArea.text) *
        StrToFloat(edtVALOR.text))
    else
        edtVALOR.text :=  '0,00';
    Exit;
  end;
```

all fields in clientdataset set currency and displayformat = #,0.00, thanks!

Comment: You've forgotten to ask a question. What specifically would you like us to help you with?

Comment: How to format this result' then edtVALOR.text := floattostr(StrToFloat(edtArea.text) * StrToFloat(edtVALOR.text))' in $ format.

Comment: What is the use case for that `Exit`?

Comment: Where is the client dataset involved in that code?

Comment: exit the function... is not correct?

Comment: I'm using livebinding

Comment: You do know that if you format `edVALOR.text` to contain the `$` format, you won't be able to use it in `StrToFloat` any longer without coding to remove the `$` formatting, right?

Comment: If this method is bind to `edtVALOR.OnChange` you will get an infinite loop

Comment: What do you think will happen, when the method reaches the `end`? It does not waiting for someone, it will exit

Comment: I'm migrating from language, I'm learning

Comment: @PabloRicardo: No matter what the method does, if it reaches the end of the method body, it will exit it anyway (and return execution to to the caller). There is no need to put `Exit` in there. `Exit`is only useful if you want to exit the method somewhere in the middle, before normal execution would end. But note that some purists say that you should never do that anyway, and that methods should only have one exit point: the final end of the method body.